# Cancelar o envio do formulário jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

Boa tarde, tenho um formulário e quero que quando o botão de `submit` seja clicado ele não recarregue a página para o envio do post coloquei o `return false;` na função `submit` do `jQuery` mas não rolou...

```
$("#form-anuncio-edita-texto").submit(function () {
        if ($("#edita-anuncio-texto").val() !== "") {

            var formData = new FormData(this);

            $("#page-load").toggleClass('sk-loading');
            $("#anuncio-edita-text-alert").hide();
            $('#modal-anuncios-3').modal('toggle');

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "modulos/paginas/" + identificador + "/process/updateMedia.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: formData
            });

            request.done(function (data) {
                $("#page-load").toggleClass('sk-loading');
                alert(data);
            });

            request.fail(function () {
                $("#page-load").toggleClass('sk-loading');
                toastNotification("<a href='index.php'>A página não pode ser carregada, se este erro persistir sujerimos que atualize a página ou clique <strong>AQUI</strong> e tente novamente.</a>", "Erro no Carregamento...", 15000, "error");
            });
        } else {
            $("#anuncio-edita-text-alert").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Quando o campo está vazio ele entra no `else` e a página não recarrega, mas quando eu informo qualquer valor ele recarrega.

ATENÇÃO: Esse exemplo é com um campo de texto que seria facilmente resolvido utilizando a função `click` do `jQuery` armazenando o conteúdo numa `var` e colocando ela no `data: {texto: vartexto}`, mas não posso utiliza-la pois nesse formulário tem um campo `FILE` onde eu vou mandar um arquivo via AJAX.

Comment: tenta evitar o evento assim: 

$("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: @eduardocosta não funcionou, ele continua recarregando a página.

Comment: E como tens o teu botão na form? se tiver type="submit" tenta mudar para type="button"

Comment: @eduardocosta se eu mudar para button o submit não é enviado não entrando na condição acima, como disse na pergunta seria fácil resolver o problema com o evento click, mas o problema é que tenho um campo file no html, não consigo pegar a informação desse campo por jQuery a não ser via submit.

Comment: Tente dar um return false dentro da chamada do metodo .submit. $("#form-anuncio-edita-texto").submit(function(){ return false; });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para evitar que o `submit` seja executado, chame a função passando o evento como parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
$("#form-anuncio-edita-texto").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

> **event.preventDefault()**
>
> Cancela o evento se for cancelável, sem parar a propagação do mesmo.

```js
$("#form-anuncio-edita-texto").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Entrei mas não enviei");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="pagina2.asp" id="form-anuncio-edita-texto">
  <button type="submit" id="btn">
    Enviar
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Não estou evitando o submit do botão já que o ID (#form-anuncio-edita-texto) é o ID do form não do botão.

Comment: Opa, não tinha o HTML imaginei que fosse o botão, mas de qualquer forma utilizando o event.preventDefault() passando o evento como parâmetro você obterá o resultado esperado.

Comment: O amigo @eduardocosta deu essa sugestão, mas não funcionou.

Comment: No exemplo que coloquei acima funciona perfeitamente, acredito que possa ser algo no seu javascript que esteja provocando um comportamento inesperado, chegou a verificar se existe erro no console?

Comment: se da algum erro eu não consigo ver, a página atualiza muito rápido antes mesmo de aparecer algo.

Comment: Tem 2 formas para você ver 1- Marcando a opção de `manter log` na ferramenta desenvolvedor, ou mude o tipo do botão para button apenas para debuggar e ver o erro.

Comment: o erro que dá é esse: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Ab (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.r.param (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:146:29)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)

Comment: O problema está em como você passa o `data` para o seu ajax, você está passando um objeto jquery e ele não está sendo capaz de interpretá-lo. Sugiro a abertura de uma nova pergunta especificando o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que tens de fazer algo assim:

```
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 <button type="button" id="submit">teste</button>
</form>

<script>
 $('#submit').click(function () {
   $('#form').submit();
 });
 $('#form').submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if //logica
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Deu o mesmo problema que aneriormente =/

Comment: E o botão têm o type="button"?